# UWP Grid Transitions

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, grid, win-universal-app

I tried to create a transition for my pop up grid (usercontrol).
It work well, but just once, after that, the transition doesn't work, furthermore, I havn't the reverse transition when I close my grid

Xaml UserControl:

```
<UserControl Visibility="Collapsed">

    <Grid Background="red">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Bottom"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.Transitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Close" Click="close_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# UserControl:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Xaml Page:

```
<Page>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <local:MyUserControl1 x:Name="popUp"/>
        <Button Content="Open" Click="Open_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C# Page:

```
private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popUp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

i think the probleme is Visibility, but i need it to show and hide my control, should i use visual state in my usercontrol ?

Comment: It seems the `EdgeUIThemeTransition` is loading one time, the transition wii load when remove the `MyUserControl1` and then add it to the page. Also you can change another transition that can add in the `Storyboard`.

Comment: Should i create a storyboard for Visibility? if yes, how activate him when i set visibility of my UserControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i use:

C# UserControl(delete the usercontrol):

```
private void close_Click(object send, RoutedEventArg e)
{
    ((Panel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
}
```

Xaml UserControl(i set the transition here)

```
<UserControl.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Botom"/>
    </TransitionCollection> 
</UserControl.Transitions>
```

c# page(create an user control):

```
MyUserControl cont = new MyUserControl();
MygridName.children.Add(cont);
```

Comment: Do you get both the forward(going in) and the backward(going out) animation when using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

In the click_Close statement have you tried using

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

because the way I am reading it, there doesn't seem to be a targeted element right now.

I admit, I have not tested this - it is just something I noticed and hopefully it works and saves you some coding. (I know just enough C# to be dangerous >=D )

Comment: yes :( it's visual studio who notify me to remove "this", and i have the same result whit "this" and "whitout. but thanks for your answer ^^

Comment: :( dang, I'll try something later - hopefully you find an answer though.

Comment: No, i have not find an answer, use Transitions is probably the wrong way, but i did'nt  know how to have the same result without it. : (